# What's the best way to create a 2*2 grid layout with a Material Card Design using Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, material-design

I'm developing an iOS app, the app is written in Objective-C. I'm wanting to create a 2*2 grid style layout for the main screen, with a 'card layout' design.  Is there a straight forward way to do this using Xcode?

Example
 [image: Mockup]

Comment: For the image you've shown, you could use Constraints only, or `UIStackView`s, or a `UICollectionView`... without a little more information, tough to say which would be better. Are these dynamic elements? Will there be exactly 4? How do you want it to look in other aspect-ratios (such as on a phone turned to landscape orientation)?